# Unity, C# перемещение камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Добрый день. Не могу как можно реализовать следующее перемещение: если нажата ЛКМ то перемещать камеру так как будто перемещаешь объект то есть как будто земля точно перемещается за курсором но должна перемещаться камера. Если просто делать примерно 
`transform.localPosition += new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));` 
то курсор не совпадает с позицией когда нажали первый раз на землю.Еще высота камеры может быть разной. Пример: нажали на дерево ЛКМ и начинаем перемещать и дерево должно совпадать с позицией курсора на экране. Думаю понятно объяснил) Еще пример: перемещение такое же и в синема когда нажимаешь альт+нажатие колесика.

Comment: я думаю всем будет проще если Вы приведёте конкретный пример кода, если он у Вас имеется.

Comment: Кода нет, потому что даже логически не представляю как это реализовать. Мне бы логически узнать что делать а запрограммирую потом сам.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить точку на поверхности объекта который вы двигаете (размещаем на нем коллайдер), если надо то еще высоту этой точки над поверхностью. Когда давят кнопку мыши запоминаем позицию в локальных координатах объекта. Далее пока не отпустили кнопку на каждом кадре высчитываем новое положение мыши на экране и в мировых координатах высчитываем положение где должен объект оказаться. Если надо чтобы он двигался по поверхности то через `Raycast` ищем точку куда мы должны его переместить на поверхности. Ну а дальше остается рассчитать дистанцию между расчетными точками и точкой в локальных координатах которую мы зафиксировали ранее.

Я обычно делаю так, создаю пустой объект который выступает в качестве цели для нового положения и двигаю его контроллером. А на объект который должен следовать за целью пишу простенький скрипт `FollowMe` в котором прописываю эту цель и порядок следования, жестко или сглажено через линейную интерполяцию. Сглаживание помогает избежать "дребезжания" при работе с устройствами ввода.